# Do employers have "enterprise" license for the employer functionality on careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Is this based on one hiring manager's openid, or is the $5000 annual fee good for an entire company?  Is it based on one geographic location?

The best way to highlight the question is with an example:

Let's say someone with a Microsoft email address pays $5000 for an annual subscription.  Does that mean all of Microsoft's hiring managers can search the database all year for all locations?

Maybe this is in the FAQ, I'll go take a look again.

EDIT:

I think the answer is "no"  hiring manager use only - based on language in the FAQ, but it is not specifically stated.  For example - if Steve Ballmer were the one who signed up, he could potentially do a search for all locations?

Again, is this location based or tied to manager?  I know of many scenarios where a manager is responsible for multiple locations.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just like Stack Overflow, you can have more than one OpenID associated, so in this case you could have two:

- a personal OpenID of the person who paid for the account and is "responsible" for it:
  `joe-smith.myopenid.com`
- a company-wide OpenID for people who need access to the account:
  `acme-corp-so-careers.myopenid.com`

That's what I'd recommend anyway

Comment: Thanks, This was more of a high level question, not a mechanical one - specifically, what is the policy from SO.  I guess that means one $5000 check from Microsoft means the entire set of hiring managers and HR folks can use the account?

Answer (score 3):

Right now we're being pretty casual about that... I can't even tell from the TOS what our official policy is.

As time goes on we'll figure out the details. Usually with these kinds of resume-searching services, you pay for a package of, say, 100 searches, or 1000 searches, at different prices, so that a big company that goes crazy ends up paying more, so I expect that in the future we'll set a maximum number of searches or messages above which you have to pay more.

Comment: OK, that clears up some details.  thanks